# How to display google adsense ads with asp.net core blazor web assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a project running on blazor and I want to add google adsense ads on blazor but I don't find any solution to run google ads on blazor.

Please help me to setup the ads!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this video!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjLEVlUA7mY

This has a very simple way of putting your add inside a component.

You properly need to create a component.

This is what I used in my project

```
 <div @key="@Guid.NewGuid()" >
 @if (Ads is not null)
 {
     @Ads
 }
 </div>

 @code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Slot { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Style { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Adsformat { get; set; } = "auto";

    private RenderFragment Ads { get; set; }


    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Ads = new RenderFragment(b =>
        {
            b.OpenElement(0, "ins");
            b.AddMultipleAttributes(1, new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("class", "adsbygoogle"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("style", $"{Style}"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("data-ad-client", "your-client-secure-code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("data-ad-slot", Slot),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("data-ad-format", Adsformat),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("data-full-width-responsive", true),
            });
            b.CloseElement();
 
            b.OpenElement(0, "script");
            b.AddContent(3, "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});");
            b.CloseElement();
       });
   }
}
```