# MAUI Blazor Hybrid Admob

Tags: c#, admob, maui, blazor-hybrid

I have a MAUI Blazor Hybrid mobile application and I want to add Admob ads.
I found a way to do so in XAML: https://www.mauiexpert.it/admob-for-maui-made-easy/

but **I would like to wrap such functionality into Blazor component** so it is easily reusable across my Blazor pages.

Yes, theoretically I can use Google AdSense but from what I read AdMob gives better PPC than AdSense.

Is there a way how to achieve this ?

Comment: There is a similar case about [How to display google adsense ads with asp.net core blazor web assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863966/how-to-display-google-adsense-ads-with-asp-net-core-blazor-web-assembly), you can refer to it.

Comment: @Liyun it is more complicated with MAUI Blazor hybrid because the Blazor part is not hosted as a website and thus officially cant have Adsense (at least from what I read). Because Adsense is registered per domain

Answer (score 0):

After some research I came to this conclusion.

**Option #1**

Google allows showing Ads in WebView just for one specific usecase and its when you have a website which contains Adsense ads and you just want to show that website inside your app in WebView control.

Src: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/webview

For that specific case you would register your webview.
Install Nuget package:
`Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` and inside `MainPage.xaml.cs` put:

```
#if ANDROID
using Android.Gms.Ads;
#endif

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;

namespace SatisFIT.Client.App;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        blazorWebView.BlazorWebViewInitialized += BlazorWebViewOnBlazorWebViewInitialized;
    }

    private void BlazorWebViewOnBlazorWebViewInitialized(object? sender, BlazorWebViewInitializedEventArgs e) {
#if ANDROID
        MobileAds.RegisterWebView(e.WebView);
#endif
    }
```

after that you put `meta-data` tag mentioned in the google doc to `AndroidManifest.xml` `<application>` tag like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <!-- Bypass APPLICATION_ID check for WebView API for Ads -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.INTEGRATION_MANAGER"
        android:value="webview"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

But as I mentioned already we cant use it just for embedding HTML of adsense ad and wrapping it into simple component.

> There is potential workaround. But Google would probably disable your advertising account if they find out. The workaround would be to create your custom `WebView` control, then register that control with `e.WebView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());` inside method `BlazorWebViewOnBlazorWebViewInitialized` and implement there request interception. So when adsense JS would like to call `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net` you intercept this request, then inside it's GET parameters you replace(2x) your local url: `0.0.0.0` to url of you website where do you have adsense allowed and theoretically u receive response with the ad.

**Option #2**

- I wasnt able to make it work
- [H5 gaming api](https://developers.google.com/ad-placement/docs/html5-game-structure) what is basically also mix of AdSense and Admob
- it uses WebView registering like option #1 but has a little bit different capabilities

**Option #3**

There is probably no other way how to achieve wrapping ad into Blazor component in Blazor Hybrid bacause you **cant** embed XAML into blazor and thats why the only way how to show google ad in your MAUI Blazor app is by using admob library: [Plugin.MauiMTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob)

With this we can create XAML ad and we can place it under or over our `BlazorWebView` component so it can overlap a part of it.